# Looping over 3 dimensional arrays in CUDA to sum their elements

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm having some problems understanding how to loop over 3 dimensional arrays with a kernel.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
// Array properties
const int width = 1;
const int height = 1;
const int depth = 1;

// Declaration of arrays
float h_A[width][height][depth];
float h_B[width][height][depth];
float h_C[width][height][depth] = {{{0}}};

// Fill up arrays
srand(time(0));
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        for(int z = 0; z < depth; z++){
            h_A[i][j][z] = rand()%1000;
            h_B[i][j][z] = rand()%1000;
        }
    }
}

// Declaration of device pointers
cudaPitchedPtr d_A, d_B, d_C;

// Allocating memory in GPU
cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(width*sizeof(float),height,depth);
cudaMalloc3D(&d_A, extent);
cudaMalloc3D(&d_B, extent);
cudaMalloc3D(&d_C, extent);

// Copying memory from host to device
cudaMemcpy3DParms p;
p.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(&h_A, sizeof(float)*width, height, depth);
p.extent = extent;
p.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

p.dstPtr = d_A;
cudaMemcpy3D(&p);
p.dstPtr = d_B;
cudaMemcpy3D(&p);
p.dstPtr = d_C;
cudaMemcpy3D(&p);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

How do I make a kernel that loops over each element in the arrays and adds them together?

Comment: Do not make a one to one translation from C/C++ to CUDA for this kind of operations. Have a look at the CUDA SDK reduction example. Think parallel :-)

Comment: Two things, if all you want is the sum you should use http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-asum simply because its optimized like crazy, aftually if all you want is the sum, then I would guess that a CPU based BLAS library would be quicker. I believe the conventional knowledge is that BLAS Level1 functions will be memory bound, and not GPU bound, keeping this kind of thing on the cpu would make sense

Comment: A full working example can be now found in the answer to [Copying from cuda 3D memory to linear memory: copied data is not where I expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107480/copying-from-cuda-3d-memory-to-linear-memory-copied-data-is-not-where-i-expecte/23052768#23052768).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example on page 21 of the CUDA 4.0 programming guide for looping over 2D array of floats:

```
// Host code
int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch,
width * sizeof(float), height);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPtr, pitch, width, height);


// Device code
__global__ void MyKernel(float* devPtr, size_t pitch, int width, int height)
{
   for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) 
    {
       float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
          for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) 
              {
              float element = row[c];
              }
     }
}
```

rewrite it to sum up elements should be easy. Additionally you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029920/1141471) thread. When efficiency is concern, you might also look on [parallel reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) approach in CUDA. This is used for example when implementing Monte Carlo simulation (see Multi Monte Carlo example).

Comment: To effectively sum up elements by CUDA is rather difficult task. See [reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) for more details.

Comment: efficiency is different topic, question is about basic idea of how to loop over an array