# The meaning of xsize and ysize fields in the output pitched pointer of cudaMalloc3D

Tags: cuda

The [documentation of `cudaMalloc3D`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g188300e599ded65c925e79eab2a57347) says

> The returned `cudaPitchedPtr` contains additional fields `xsize` and
>   `ysize`, the logical width and height of the allocation, which are
>   equivalent to the width and height extent parameters provided by the
>   programmer during allocation.

However, if I run the following minimum example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<device_launch_parameters.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define Nrows 64
#define Ncols 64
#define Nslices 16

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
// --- Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { exit(code); }
    }
}

void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    // --- 3D pitched allocation and host->device memcopy
    cudaExtent extent = make_cudaExtent(Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows, Nslices);
    cudaPitchedPtr devPitchedPtr;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc3D(&devPitchedPtr, extent));

    printf("xsize = %i; xsize in bytes = %i; ysize = %i\n", devPitchedPtr.xsize, devPitchedPtr.pitch, devPitchedPtr.ysize);

    return 0;
}
```

I receive:

```
xsize = 256; xsize in bytes = 512; ysize = 64
```

So, `ysize` is actually equal to `Nrows`, but `xsize` is different from either `Ncols` or `xsize in bytes / sizeof(float)`.

Could you please help me understanding the meaning of the `xsize`and `ysize` fields in the `cudaPitchedPtr` of `cudaMalloc3D`?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

My system: `Windows 10`, `CUDA 8.0`, `GT 920M`, `cc 3.5`.

Comment: xsize is the pitch width you requested in bytes. pitch is the actual pitch width in bytes. ysize is the number of rows you requested

Comment: Not the sentences "Allocates *at least* width * height * depth bytes of linear memory" and "The function *may pad* the allocation..." in the doc.

Comment: @talonmies Thank you very much for your prompt comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsize` = `Ncols * sizeof(float)`

`xsize` is the *logical* width (in bytes) of the allocation, as opposed to the *pitched* width

logical width = 256 bytes

pitched width = 512 bytes

It is equivalent (identical) to the width parameter you provided during allocation (i.e. the first parameter you passed to `make_cudaExtent`)

Comment: Thank you Robert for your prompt answer. Now it is clear to me that `xsize` is the number of columns "measured" in `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

A very related and working example to this question (@JackOLantern your own answer in another post) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23052768/6269369) that shows how to use `cudaMalloc3D` and etc.

I have learnt a rule of thumb that somehow answers this question and I want to share it with you: "In the context of of CUDA library, unless we are working with `cudaArrays`, `width` means `nCols * sizeof(datatype)` in bytes and `pitch` means `width + 0` or `width + some padding`(depending on the size of the array and GPU hardware) in bytes."

**PS**. When working with CUDA arrays, we define `width` in terms of number of elements(not number of bytes) in a row(`nCols`). That's because CUDA Arrays take care of internal memory layout and we don't need to provide `width` in terms of number of bytes.